# Low birth weight in infants: A binary data example

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binary-data

Using the `birthwt` data from R's `MASS` package, I'm trying to solve the problem as posed in *Modern Applied Statistics with S-PLUS by Venables and Ripley:*

The main interest is in the low birth weight, that is, which, if any, of the variables age, lwt, race, smoke, ptl, ht, ui, and ftv are predictive of whether or not a new-born baby will have his/her birth weight less than 2.5 kg.

The variables are described as:

```
low birth weight - less than 2.5 kg (0, otherwise 1)
age - age of mother in years
lwt - weight of mother at last menstrual period (lbs)
race - white/black/other
smoke - smoking status during pregnancy (0/1)
ptl - number of previous premature labours
ht - history of hypertension (0/1)
ui - has uterine irritability (0/1)
ftv - number of physician visits in the first trimester
bwt - actual birth weight (grams)
```

I understand that the code below concentrates on predicting if birth weight is low from the variables (excluding bwt). However, I am unsure how the process would be different for the question I posed. Am I suppose to run the code below, but keep some of the data "set aside" for predictive purposes, based on the results for the portion of the data I analyzed?

```
bwt <- with(birthwt, {
race <- factor(race, labels = c("white", "black", "other"))
ptd <- factor(ptl > 0)
ftv <- factor(ftv)
levels(ftv)[-(1:2)] <- "2+"
data.frame(low = factor(low), age, lwt, race, smoke = (smoke > 0),
           ptd, ht = (ht > 0), ui = (ui > 0), ftv)
})
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
glm(low ~ ., binomial, bwt)
```

Comment: This is a retrospective study: data on mothers were collected once the weight of the baby was known. One way to approach the question is to analyze whether any of the predictors has an impact on the probability of observing a low birth weight. This is more of an explanatory approach than a predictive one. This specific study does not include matched cases (in another study by Hosmer & Lemeshow, mothers who gave birth to a low birth weight baby were matched to 3 mothers of normal birth weight babies of the same age). But maybe I don't understand what you mean by "the question I posed".

Comment: The "question I posed" here is one posed by the authors, as noted in my post:

The main interest is in the low birth weight, that is, which, if any, of the variables age, lwt, race, smoke, ptl, ht, ui, and ftv are predictive of whether or not a new-born baby will have his/her birth weight less than 2.5 kg.

Comment: That was my understanding, but I was not sure. Excellent read by the way! This is merely an exercice about multivariate regression: finding interesting (risk) predictors, after having adjusted for mother's baseline characteristics (age and weight). Two straightforward questions: (1) are predictors really all that important (this has to do with model interpretation), (2) what's the "best model", i.e., can we find a subset of regressors that perform equally well in term of model fit indices (this is model selection), if this does make sense of course.

Comment: In regards to determining which predictors impact the probability of observing a low birth weight, is it as simple solving the logistic model:
$$y = \ln\left(\frac{p}{1 - p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \cdots + \beta_kx_k + \varepsilon$$

for $p$, so:
$$p = \frac{e^y}{1 + e^y}$$

then fitting the model:
$$glm(p \sim predictor 1 + predictor 2 + \cdots)$$

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Then you'll get adjusted oods-ratios, p-value, etc. The question is to identify predictors that are important in explaining the `low` variable, and whether some are more important than other (taking into account the observed prevalence of events like `ht` or `ui`). Other than that, is the a "good" model or not, in term of model fit indices (AIC, BIC, $R^2$ or whatever)?